Did I really get 40 points in cribbage?
I have a hazy memory of playing cribbage as a kid. In my memory, with my hand and the cat (not the pegging round), I got a total of 40 points. Is that possible? If so, how did I do it?

Yes, it's possible. From Wikipedia's Cribbage Statistics - Maximum Scores (fifth bullet):

The highest score as a dealer from the hand and crib is 53. The starter must be a 5, the hand must be J555, with the Jack suit matching the starter (score 29), and the crib must be 4466 (score 24, for 15-12 and quadruple run of 3 for another 12), or vice versa.

The number of ways to get a score of 40, much less than the maximum 53, are likely numerous. One example with a starter of 5 is 24 in hand (4466, for 15-12 and quadruple run of three for another 12) and 16 in crib (5TTK, for 15-12 and two pair makes 16).
